# Identifying an outlier nominal group different than the norm, based on an ordinal dependent variable

Tags: spss, survey, group-differences

As part of my graduate thesis, I've measured the satisfaction levels of a couple hundred respondents across 7 districts of a city about a local public service, using a 4-point ordinal Likert scale (ranging from 1: Very dissatisfied to 4: Very satisfied). What I'm trying is to see if there are any districts that significantly differ from the norm of all districts as a whole, not just to each other, in terms of satisfaction. I'm familiar with difference tests such as Kruskal Wallis on the SPSS program that I'm using right now, but these tests often are built for pairwise comparisons, and not really for 4+ groups of the independent variable such as my case. Therefore I'd like to ask if there any appropriate methodology that I can use to do this effectively. Thanks everyone and appreciate all your insights. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Do I understand correctly, you want to investigate whether the medians of your districts differ from the overall median of all districts? This may not be the best way, but since nobody else has commented: I guess you could use 7 one-sample median tests and use the overall median as the hypothesized median. However, if you did this you'd need to manually adjust your critical p-value as lower because you'd be running 7 tests "as if" they were independent.

As for differences between districts, Kruskal-Wallis is the non-parameteric equivalent of ANOVA, so you can have more than 2 groups in K-W, and it does give you an omnibus test for any differences between 7 groups, as well as the pairwise comparisons.